# Sublime Text Regex or wildcard

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I would like to find all instances of the following in Sublime Text and delete it. I dont need to check the inner text so:

this:

```
<itembinlist>W323423</itembinlist> or
<itembinlist>W43434</itembinlist>
```

would match and then deleted.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Regex search for `<itembinlist>[^<]+</itembinlist>`, replace with nothing.

Comment: **Note**: One also needs to enable regular expressions in search for this to work: Check the first box on the left of the search bar (the one with an '\*\' on it) or toggle with Alt+R.
(Btw, in sublime you can also use .* instead of [^<])×An error occurred during comment submission×An error occurred during comment submission×An error occurred during comment submission

Comment: Any chance there is a way to use this for multiple lines of code? For example: `<table id="header">*wildcard_here*</body></html>` ? I've tried the [^<]+ as well as .* but neither work.